# Sending SMS using count down timer

Tags: android, sms, countdowntimer

I have been trying to develop an android application where the SMS is sent in future date. The future date is taken as input from the user.The problem here is that how to use the Count Down Timer  for long periods of time like days and hours.Any help is appreciated.

```
package com.example.sked;

//import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Calendar;

//import java.util.Locale;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.DatePicker;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TimePicker;

import android.widget.Toast;



public class ScheduleActivity extends Activity
{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

        final int year_set=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int month_set=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int day_set=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        final int hr_set=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        final int min_set=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        final   DatePicker dp_c = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        final   TimePicker tp_c = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        dp_c.updateDate(year_set, month_set, day_set); //Setting current date in date picker //

        tp_c.setCurrentHour(hr_set);  //Setting current time in time picker //
        tp_c.setCurrentMinute(min_set);


        //For Scheduling a message//
        final Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_message);
        {
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Processing here 
            EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reci_number);
            final String phno= text .getText().toString();

            EditText text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
            final String msg= text1.getText().toString();

            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();//Calculating current date in milliseconds//

            final int year_curr=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            final int month_curr=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day_curr=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            final int hr_curr=cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            final int min_curr=cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            day_curr= year_curr*365+month_curr*30;//Converting year to days and months to days//


            long day_curr_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(day_curr, TimeUnit.DAYS);

            long hours_curr_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(hr_curr, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            long mins_curr_mil=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(min_curr, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

            final long elapsedtimer_curr= day_curr_mil+hours_curr_mil+mins_curr_mil;



            DatePicker dp = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1); 
            int day = dp.getDayOfMonth(); //Receiving date from the user//
            int month = dp.getMonth() + 1;
            int year = dp.getYear();

            TimePicker tp=(TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
            int hours= tp.getCurrentHour();//Receiving time from the user//
            int minutes= tp.getCurrentMinute();

            day= year*365+month*30;//Converting year to days and months to days//


            long day_sel=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(day, TimeUnit.DAYS);

            long hours_sel=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(hours, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            long mins_sel=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(minutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

            long elapsedtimer_sel= day_sel+hours_sel+mins_sel;

            if(phno.length()==10)//Checking length of the mobile number//
            {
            if(msg.length()<=160 && msg.length()>0) //Checking length of the message//
            {


                        final String phoneNumber = phno;
                        final String message = msg;


                        long elapsed_act=elapsedtimer_sel-elapsedtimer_curr;

                        new CountDownTimer(elapsed_act, 1000) {

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                            }

                            public void onFinish() 
                            {
                                /*Sending the message*/
                                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
                            }
                         }.start();


                        final AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScheduleActivity.this, 0);

                          //set  the dialog  
                            dlgAlert.setMessage("Message successfully scheduled at the specified time & date");
                            dlgAlert.setTitle("Success");
                            dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                            dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);
                            dlgAlert.create().show();




            }  

            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Message too long or too short .... cannot send ... :( ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Check the number Entered",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }


        }

        );



        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.schedule, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: you should use alarm manager to achieve rather timer. Timer is for short term use and when application is active. But when you want to process it from background AlarmService is proper approach to use.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Are the conversions from the days to milliseconds and minutes to milliseconds correct ?.... am i doing it right ?

Comment: @Saikanthk did u get the solution for it?

Comment: @Beginner Yes i did as Biraj said , it works .... because when we use the countdown timer the count down takes place only when the application is active.But we need to run the millsecs timer even after the app is closed, AlarmService does that perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference help i am posting this answer .You can get help from this because i have used time delay to send notification so you can modify it and use it

```
public class AutoNotification extends Activity {
    private Timer refresh = null;
    private final long refreshDelay = 5 * 1000;//this delay will be your time that the user will provide you
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_notification);

        sensSMSThread = new sensSMSRequest();
        sensSMSThread.start();

    }
    class sensSMSRequest extends Thread {
        boolean sendHttpRequest;
        public sensSMSRequest() {

            sendHttpRequest = true;
        }

        public void stopSendingHttpRequest() {
            sendHttpRequest = false;
        }

        protected void onStop() {
            sensSMSThread.stopSendingHttpRequest();
            super.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (sendHttpRequest) {
                sendSms();


                SystemClock.sleep(refreshDelay);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope somehow it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Create an intent filter :

```
 static {
    s_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
}
```

and a broadcast receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver m_timeChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
            action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED))
        {
           //if(current time == sechduled time)  doyourWork();
        }
    }
};
```

register the receiver in Service:

```
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(m_timeChangedReceiver, s_intentFilter);     
}
```

Note : *Don't forget to start the Service again after device reboot.*